# Trying to save variable with different name in for loop

Tags: python, save

I am trying to use np.savetxt in order to save the results of a variable in a .txt file. The code is pretty simple.

```
for n in range(2000,11000,2000): 
    avdist = [0]*(np.max(idx)+1)  #average distance of the vectors belonging to their corresponding cluster
    avdist1 = [0]*(np.max(idx)+1)
    for i in range(0, np.max(idx)+1):  
        avdist[i] = np.mean([np.linalg.norm(e[x]-centroids[i]) for x in range(len(e)) if idx[x] == i])
        avdist1[i] = np.mean([np.linalg.norm(e[x]-centroids[i]) for x in range(len(e)) if idx[x] != i])
    np.savetxt('avdist{0}.txt'.format(n), avdist)
```

But i am getting an IndexError: tuple index out of range.

Why is this happening? I was expecting there result to be avdist2000, avdist4000, etc.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1034, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: You need to provide more code (what is 'various calculations'). The `IndexError` is not being raised from the line of code you have provided.

Comment: check it now, i edited my post

Comment: Thanks. Can you also provide your stack trace?

Comment: i hope this is what you mean :)

Comment: Yes, that's it.  The trace clearly indicates that `ncol = X.shape[1]` on line 1 is the culprit.  You are not including this code in your question at all which makes it impossible to troubleshoot further.  But apparently `shape` only contains one element (if even that), so the index `[1]` is out of range (do you mean `[0]` or does it not contain what you assume?)

Comment: ok, i solved it by using the numpy.save instead of nupmpy.savetxt. For some reason it works :)